# run uncompressed and minified jQuery files at the same time

Tags: jquery, minify

Is it possible to run both the uncompressed and minified versions of jQuery on the same website?

I have two web scripts that I am attempting to merge together, one that utilizes uncompressed jQuery and one that utilized minified (same version - 1.8.3). I currently have issues using both files at the same time - specifically, the scripts that utilize the uncompressed file are not triggering.

Note: This is just for development purposes, both programs will be converted to use minifed once put into production. Just trying to save some time and avoid doing so right now.

Comment: You cannot include jquery twice.

Comment: Why not just use uncompressed version for development and minified for production?

Comment: Please see my new question which includes the code here, and thank you for the help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969814/jquery-minified-code-is-not-loading-with-uncompressed-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whether they are minified or not they should be the same. Minification only reduces the file size, it **shouldn't** alter the content of the files. It just removes white space and new lines, etc.

That said you wouldn't load to copies of Jquery so why load one minifed and one not. Just load the minified one.

Comment: You make sense, but for some reason which I just can't figure out, the first script that utilizes the minified version of jQuery won't work with the uncompressed version, and the second script that utilizes the uncompressed version won't work with minified jQuery.

Comment: Download both(compressed and uncompressed) files from jquery site and then try. If still it has issues then you need to fix your code instead of bothering about these jquery files. Probably you can post your code

Comment: I will select your answers as best - please take a peek at the actual code in my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969814/jquery-minified-code-is-not-loading-with-uncompressed-jquery